# How to compare an array of integers and display them from greatest to least in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, logic

I'm working on some exercises from the Cplusplus.com website in order to improve my programming and to learn and relearn some material from a class I have taken this year and the problem below is what I am working and specifically the last bolded portion.

> Write a program that asks the user to enter the number of pancakes eaten for breakfast by 10 different people (Person 1, Person 2, ..., Person 10)
>   Once the data has been entered the program must analyze the data and output which person ate the most pancakes for breakfast.
>
> **Modify the program so that it outputs a number of pancakes eaten of all 10 people like for example..**
>
> **Person 4: ate 10 pancakes**
>
> **Person 3: ate 7 pancakes**
>
> **Person 8: ate 4 pancakes**
>
> **etc...**

Here is what I have so far

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void getPancakesEaten(int pancakes[]);
void comparePancakesEaten(int pancakes[]);
void displayOrder(int pancakes[]);


/**********************************************************************
* Gets the amount of Pancakes eaten
***********************************************************************/
void getPancakesEaten(int pancakes[])
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Person " << i + 1 << ": ate ";
        cin >> pancakes[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
}

/**********************************************************************
* Compares the amount of pancakes eaten with each person
***********************************************************************/
void comparePancakesEaten(int pancakes[])
{
    if(pancakes[0] > pancakes[1] && pancakes[0] > pancakes[2] && pancakes[0] >               pancakes[3] && pancakes[0] > pancakes[4] && pancakes[0] > pancakes[5] && pancakes[0] > pancakes[6] && pancakes[0] > pancakes[7] && pancakes[0] > pancakes[8] && pancakes[9])
{
    cout << "Person 1 ate " << pancakes[0] << " pancakes" << endl;
}

else if(pancakes[1] > pancakes[0] && pancakes[1] > pancakes[2] && pancakes[1] > pancakes[3] && pancakes[1] > pancakes[4] && pancakes[1] > pancakes[5] && pancakes[1] > pancakes[6] && pancakes[1] > pancakes[7] && pancakes[1] > pancakes[8] && pancakes[1] > pancakes[9])
{
    cout << "Person 2 ate " << pancakes[1] << " pancakes" << endl;
}

else if(pancakes[2] > pancakes[0] && pancakes[2] > pancakes[1] && pancakes[2] > pancakes[3] && pancakes[2] > pancakes[4] && pancakes[2] > pancakes[5] && pancakes[2] > pancakes[6] && pancakes[2] > pancakes[7] && pancakes[2] > pancakes[8] && pancakes[2] > pancakes[9])
{
    cout << "Person 3 ate " << pancakes[2] << " pancakes" << endl;
}

else if(pancakes[3] > pancakes[0] && pancakes[3] > pancakes[2] && pancakes[3] > pancakes[1] && pancakes[3] > pancakes[4] && pancakes[3] > pancakes[5] && pancakes[3] > pancakes[6] && pancakes[3] > pancakes[7] && pancakes[3] > pancakes[8] && pancakes[3] > pancakes[9])
{
    cout << "Person 4 ate " << pancakes[3] << " pancakes" << endl;
}

else if(pancakes[4] > pancakes[0] && pancakes[4] > pancakes[2] && pancakes[4] > pancakes[3] && pancakes[4] > pancakes[1] && pancakes[4] > pancakes[5] && pancakes[4] > pancakes[6] && pancakes[4] > pancakes[7] && pancakes[4] > pancakes[8] && pancakes[4] > pancakes[9])
{
    cout << "Person 5 ate " << pancakes[4] << " pancakes" << endl;
}

else if(pancakes[5] > pancakes[0] && pancakes[5] > pancakes[2] && pancakes[5] > pancakes[3] && pancakes[5] > pancakes[4] && pancakes[5] > pancakes[1] && pancakes[5] > pancakes[6] && pancakes[5] > pancakes[7] && pancakes[5] > pancakes[8] && pancakes[5] > pancakes[9])
{
    cout << "Person 6 ate " << pancakes[5] << " pancakes" << endl;
}

else if(pancakes[6] > pancakes[0] && pancakes[6] > pancakes[2] && pancakes[6] > pancakes[3] && pancakes[6] > pancakes[4] && pancakes[6] > pancakes[5] && pancakes[6] > pancakes[1] && pancakes[6] > pancakes[7] && pancakes[6] > pancakes[8] && pancakes[6] > pancakes[9])
{
    cout << "Person 7 ate " << pancakes[6] << " pancakes" << endl;
}

else if(pancakes[7] > pancakes[0] && pancakes[7] > pancakes[2] && pancakes[7] > pancakes[3] && pancakes[7] > pancakes[4] && pancakes[7] > pancakes[5] && pancakes[7] > pancakes[6] && pancakes[7] > pancakes[1] && pancakes[7] > pancakes[8] && pancakes[7] > pancakes[9])
{
    cout << "Person 8 ate " << pancakes[7] << " pancakes" << endl;
}

else if(pancakes[8] > pancakes[0] && pancakes[8] >  pancakes[2] && pancakes[8] > pancakes[3] && pancakes[8] > pancakes[4] && pancakes[8] > pancakes[5] && pancakes[8] > pancakes[6] && pancakes[8] > pancakes[7] && pancakes[8] > pancakes[1] && pancakes[8] > pancakes[9])
{
    cout << "Person 9 ate " << pancakes[8] << " pancakes" << endl;
}

else if(pancakes[9] > pancakes[0] && pancakes[9] > pancakes[2] && pancakes[9] > pancakes[3] && pancakes[9] > pancakes[4] && pancakes[9] > pancakes[5] && pancakes[9] > pancakes[6] && pancakes[9] > pancakes[7] && pancakes[9] > pancakes[8] && pancakes[9] > pancakes[1])
{
    cout << "Person 10 ate " << pancakes[9] << " pancakes" << endl;
}

cout << "\n";
}

/**********************************************************************
* Displays the order in which person ate the most pancakes to the least
***********************************************************************/
void displayOrder(int pancakes[])
{
    for(int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            if(pancakes[j] > pancakes[j + 1])
            {
                int temp = pancakes[j + 1];

                pancakes[j + 1]= pancakes[j];

                pancakes[j]=temp;
            }
        }

    cout << "Person " << i + 1 << ": ate " << pancakes[i] << " pancake(s)" << endl;

   }

}

/**********************************************************************
* Runs the Entire Program
***********************************************************************/
int main()
{
    int pancakes[256];
    getPancakesEaten(pancakes);
    comparePancakesEaten(pancakes);
    displayOrder(pancakes);
}
```

The problem I have running into is that when I try display the correct order the person associated with the number of pancakes is sometimes incorrect based on input for example.

```
Person 1: ate 12
Person 2: ate 22
Person 3: ate 3
Person 4: ate 4
Person 5: ate 5
Person 6: ate 6
Person 7: ate 7
Person 8: ate 8
Person 9: ate 9
Person 10: ate 10
Person 2 ate 22 pancakes
Person 10: ate 22 pancake(s)
Person 9: ate 12 pancake(s)
Person 8: ate 10 pancake(s)
Person 7: ate 9 pancake(s)
Person 6: ate 8 pancake(s)
Person 5: ate 7 pancake(s)
Person 4: ate 6 pancake(s)
Person 3: ate 5 pancake(s)
Person 2: ate 4 pancake(s)
Person 1: ate 3 pancake(s)
```

Why isn't value that I entered for "Person 2" showing at "Person 10" instead? Is it because of my for loop in my `displayOrder` function?

Comment: _"Where in my code am I going wrong?"_ [That's what debuggers are purposed for](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)!

Comment: asking for help debugging is off topic - however this might be of use https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort your array before you then display it.  Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void getPancakesEaten(int pancakes[10]);
void displayOrder(int pancakes[10]);


/**********************************************************************
* Gets the amount of Pancakes eaten
***********************************************************************/
void getPancakesEaten(int pancakes[10])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Person " << i + 1 << ": ate ";
        cin >> pancakes[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
}

/**********************************************************************
* Displays the order in which person ate the most pancakes to the least
***********************************************************************/
void displayOrder(int pancakes[10])
{
    int order[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        order[i] = i;

    sort(order, order+10, [&pancakes](int a, int b){ return pancakes[a] > pancakes[b]; });

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        cout << "Person " << order[i] + 1 << ": ate " << pancakes[order[i]] << " pancake(s)" << endl;
}

/**********************************************************************
* Runs the Entire Program
***********************************************************************/
int main()
{
    int pancakes[10];
    getPancakesEaten(pancakes);
    displayOrder(pancakes);
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/6xooiE)

Comment: In both of your for loops in the displayOrder function why did you iterate the item before ++i instead of i++?

Comment: `++i` and `i++` both increment `i`, but `++i` is slightly more efficient as it performs the increment first and then returns the result, whereas `i++` returns the old value after the increment is performed. In a loop like this, it doesn't really matter one way or the other, but I prefer to use `++i` instead of `i++` to avoid the unused overhead

Comment: Is the sort function something built into C++ when you do the #include <algorithm>?

Comment: @JustinBengtson: yes, it is the [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) algorithm in the STL.